# Separar una lista de Haskell en una tupla de pares e impares

Tags: haskell

Tengo la siguiente función:

```
ParesImpares:: [Integer] -> ([Integer],[Integer])
```

Tengo que sacar de una lista los pares e impares:

```
ParesImpares [3,2,4,5,7]
```

-> `([2,4],[3,5,7])`

Mi código hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
    paresImpares :: [Integer] -> ([Integer],[Integer])
    paresImpares [] = ([],[])
    paresImpares [x] 
    | x `mod` 2 == 0 = ([x],[])
    | otherwise = ([],[x])
```

Tengo definido un caso base, pero la verdad es que no se como seguir. Tenía pensado algo como:

```
ParesImpares(x:xs) = ParesImpares [x]
```

Pero claro, sólo me evalúa el primer elemento de la lista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay una solución más directa:

```
import Data.List (partition) 

paresImpares :: Integral a => [a] -> ([a],[a])
paresImpares = partition even
```

Comment: LLevas razón, el problema de estos ejercicios es que aun tengo que hacerlos con un nivel básico en Haskell por lo que digamos que no puedo hacer "trampa" usando librerias aparte como este "partition". De todos modos gracias ! Espero tus respuestas en mis futuras preguntas en Haskell

Comment: Bueno, no sé si llamarlo "trampa". En el enunciado no se indica el modo de resolver el problema. Este tipo de problemas, donde se trata de separar los elementos que cumplen una condición de los que no, se conocen como *"particiones"*. De ahí que buscando un poco no sea dificil encontrar en un módulo tan común como `Data.List`.

Comment: Es decir vaya con "trampa" me refiero, que son ejercicios de la facultad y no se me permite usar otras librerias ,debería de haberlo especificado en el enunciado, muchas gracias

Comment: Me parece más conveniente evitar en lo más posible llamara librerías externas, a no ser que sea absolutamente necesario. Esto complica sobre todo a programadores inexpertos.

Comment: `Data.List` es parte del paquete `base` perteneciente a la especificación del lenguaje ([Haskell 2010 report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/)). No entiendo porqué hay que evitar su uso si no se especifica nada en el enunciado sobre cómo resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno he encontrado una respuesta:

```
paresImpares :: Integral a => [a] -> ([a],[a])
paresImpares [] = ([],[])
paresImpares (x:xs)
| x `mod` 2 == 0 = (x:pares,impares)
| otherwise = (pares, x:impares)
where (pares,impares) = paresImpares xs
```

Esto funciona perfectamente `x`mod`2` se puede sustituir por `even`